# Maximise area for a given perimeter, etc. - Which branch of maths?

Tags: calculus, geometry, reference-request, optimization

It's a known fact that if you have a closed loop made of flexible wire, it will enclose the maximum area when bent into a circle.

But how is this proved?

Also a harder question I was curious about: If two ends of a flexible wire of length $l$ are tied to the ends of a straight rigid rod of length $d$ ($d<l$), then what is the maximum two dimensional area enclosable by the wire and rod.

I'm just curious as to what kind of methods are used for solving such questions.

One method would probably be calculus, but I couldn't figure out how to even approach such a problem (apart from the fact that the formulae for area under a curve and length of a curve are probably required). I tried googling too, I couldn't find much.

P.S. I'm not asking for the exact solutions to the above questions (which I probably won't even understand), rather the branches of maths used to solve them.

Comment: All right, I do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The branch you are looking for is "calculus of variations".

A very good introduction is given in:

(http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~olver/ln_/cv.pdf)

Remark: All the papers by Peter Olver are advisable.